# Android UI with no buttons?

Tags: android-layout, android, android-button

I am trying to create an android TABLET application for my grandma who is sufferring from Mild cognitive impairement. One of the features of the app is intelligent schedulers/reminders .For ex: The app would say "Did you take your red pill?"  Yes or No.  If its no  or no reply , then a text message is send to my mobile .

Now her hands shiver and shake so eventhough the buttons are huge for Yes or No she tends to press the wrong one  by mistake. IS there any alternative to create a UI such that she doesnt hve to depend on the button?
Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though i have no knowledge about android, i have a work-around with the design idea:

Let there be only one big button: "Yes"
If she hasn't taken the pill, then she should NOT press the button, but rather go and take the pill, and then press "yes". Until then, the app would repetitively ask the question every 30 seconds or so (may be with a sound alarm).

Comment: The app should send a text message if she doesn't reply or presses no.So in this case we do not want to hear 'NO'(fair enough) but how do we know if the patient hasn't taken the  pill??

Comment: May be we can keep a time limit, like if she doesn't press "yes" for n minutes (n= 5 to 30 mins depending on type of medicine and urgency), then the app will send the text message.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask her touch right side or top left corner... or slide form left to right for yes and from right to left for no.

We have an accelerometer. SO we can tilt it different ways or rotate. Or knock it once time for yes and twice for no.

You can use voice commands. You can use camera as input. For example, show red card for no and gree for yes.

You can even use NFC tags... or connect big hardware buttons or some kind of keyboard...

Comment: Good suggestions, but if the user will shake this might not be such a viable solution though.

Comment: Yeah... it's hard to choose the best way... author should run some experiments

Comment: Sliding can be eliminated because it would be difficult for such patients to remember which part to slide and there could be a chance of confusion.Remembering the knock is also not a good idea for the same reasons above.Voice Command is one alternative but I wonder would it be complex to develop...Intention is to make the app as simple as possible yet help old people.

Comment: the app would send a text message if she doesnt reply or presses no.

Answer (score 2):

you can use speech to text. if she says no then match it with string "NO" and if yes then match is with "YES". OR you can use swipe as left to right for no and right to left for yes

Comment: speech to text is already told before and is a good alternative but i still require something that would respond based on touch to scree....swiping left to screen is not a good alternative when you have shaking hands.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can increase the touch area, like half screen for YES an the other one for NO. And replace the texts for colors like Green or Red.